# Merge array property of descendant objects

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, array-merge

I have a following class hierarchy, which shown in a reproduction script below:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class A
    {
        public $config = array(
            'param1' => 1,
            'param2' => 2
        );

        public function __construct(array $config = null){
            $this->config = (object)(empty($config) ? $this->config : array_merge($this->config, $config));
        }
    }

class B extends A
    {
        public $config = array(
            'param3' => 1
        );

        public function __construct(array $config = null){
            parent::__construct($config);

            // other actions
        }
    }

$test = new B();

var_dump($test);
?>
```

Output:

```
object(B)#1 (1) {
  ["config"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["param3"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

What I wanted, is that `A::$config` not be overriden by `B::$config`. There might be a lot of descendant classes from `B`, where I would like to change `$config`, but I need that those `$config` values to merge / overwrite if match `$config` values of all it's parents.

**Q:** How can I do that ?

I've tried to use `array_merge()` but in non-static mode those variables just override themselves. Is there a way to achieve merge effect for class tree without `static` (late static binding) ?

Comment: You probably *can* do that with a lot of `Reflection` and introspection, examining the current classes, its parent, its parent etc. and merging the arrays. See http://php.net/reflectionclass.

Comment: @deceze Write answer for it, so it will be useful in future for other users. :)

Comment: @deceze well, there would be a lot of overheat, no?

Comment: @CORRUPT Yes there would be. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restructure how your extended class is instantiated

```
class B extends A
{
    private $defaults = array('param3' => 1);
    public function __construct(array $config = null){
        parent::__construct($config?array_merge($this->defaults, $config):$this->defaults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, will reconsider. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is you want to keep `A` intact is to make `B` an `A` [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: @CORRUPT it will work, but see the changes he has made by changing `public $config` to `private $defaults`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar they have `protected` visibility scope in the original souce. If really, it doesn't matter `;)`.

Comment: @CORRUPT Its your choice to select best answer for your problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of declaring a `$config` property with values that you're going to change in the constructor, it's better to declare those values as default values. This is also described in Orangepill's answer:

```
class A
{
    public $config;

    private $defaults = array(
        'param1' => 1,
        'param2' => 2,
    );

    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        $this->config = (object)($config + $this->defaults);
    }
}
```

A few twists there; by declaring the default value of the `$config` constructor argument as an empty array, you can simplify your code by using [array operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) like I did above. Undefined keys in `$config` are filled in by `$this->defaults`.

The extended class will look very similar:

```
class B extends A
{
    private $defaults = array(
        'param3' => 1
    );

    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config + $this->defaults);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Orangepill also, it is more accurate. I end up with this, but you pointed me to reconsider `$defaults` case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/reflectionclass). Start by introspecting `$this`, use `getProperty()`, then use `getParentClass()` to do the same on the parent class and its parent etc. and merge the resulting arrays together.

This is probably *not* the best solution for the problem you're facing though.

Comment: I like that, but there is an overheat. Hope someone might find it heandy. But not in my situation. +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what you are looking for. Adapted from [Inherit static properties in subclass without redeclaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751719/inherit-static-properties-in-subclass-without-redeclaration/34099332#34099332)

```
<?php
class MyParent {
    public static $config = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);

    public static function getConfig() {
        $ret = array();
        $c = get_called_class();
        do {
            $ret = array_merge($c::$config, $ret);
        } while(($c = get_parent_class($c)) !== false);
        return $ret;
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {
    public static $config = array('a' => 5, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);
    public function myMethod($config) {
        $config = array_merge(self::getConfig(), $config);
    }
}

class SubChild extends MyChild {
    public static $config = array('e' => 7);
}

var_export(MyChild::getConfig());
// result: array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, )

$mc = new MyChild();
var_export($mc->myMethod(array('b' => 6)));
// result: array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 6, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, )

var_export(SubChild::getConfig());
// result: array ( 'a' => 5, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 7, )
```

Comment: It works the same way for `static` classes. In my case there was non-`statics`. Still it will work, though. Thanks anyway.